# Cocoa Swift: How to ensure WKWebView will load url request

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration, xcode10.2

I'm implementing an `WKWebView` but when there is an issue with the network such slow network connection the `WKWebView` loads blank page. Here is my implementation:

```
func loadWebView() {
    if let url = URL(string: self.urlLbl.stringValue){
        let request  = URLRequest.init(url: url)
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: self.customView.frame)
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.webView.frame = customView.bounds
        self.webView.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]
        self.webView.wantsLayer = true
        self.webView.customUserAgent = userAgentStr
        self.webView.load(request)
        self.webView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.cgColor

        self.view.needsDisplay = true
        self.webView.load(request)
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        self.customView.addSubview(self.webView)

    }
}
```

My question to you guys there is a way to know if the request load and if didn't there is a way to reload the request?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: You're loading the request twice, which is likely to cause trouble. I also recommend adding the view to its superview before you load the request (may not matter, but I would still do it in that order). You're also setting the frame wo webView to `customView.frame`, but I'm pretty certain you mean `customView.bounds`. You may get away with using `.frame` there, but I wouldn't rely on that.

Comment: @RobNapier, That is not the issue. The issue is the when the network is slow the the WebView is load black page.

Comment: The delegate will receive a message (`webView(_:didFail:withError:)`) if there is a failure.

Comment: @RobNapier, the connection slow there is no error even this function it never gets call `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!)`

Comment: `didCommit` occurs when you start receiving data. You're probably thining about `didStartProvisionalNavigation`. You can also check `didFailProvisionalNavigation`, but I'd still start by getting rid of the double-load.

Comment: @RobNapier didFailProvisionalNavigation it gets call and I was able to reload the page after that. Thank you